# Отфильтровать список

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Есть список

```
lst = ['x', 'x123', 'x2345', 'x23461243']
def function(lst):
    for x in lst:
        for i in lst:
            if x in i:
                mass.remove(x)
```

Нужно получить список всех значений, в которых присутствует `x`, а одиночный `x` из списка убрать.

```
returning_mass = ['x123', 'x2345', 'x23461243']
```

Как это сделать? Код выше работает некорректно.

Comment: Определитесь, требуется сортировка или фильтрация?

Comment: Если у нас только x, то мы удаляем элемент, а если x и еще что-то то оставляем и потом сортируем список, верно?

Comment: `returning_mass = [i for i in lst if i != 'x']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = ['x', 'x123', 'x2345', 'x23461243', '43286452378']
returning_mass = [i for i in lst if 'x' in i and i != 'x']
print(returning_mass)
```

Немного доработал ответ @gil9red, добавил проверку того, что 'x' присутствует в элементе массива.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ['x', 'x123', 'x2345', 'x23461243', '43286452378']
mask = 'x'
returning_mass = [i.replace(mask,'') for i in data if mask in i]
print(returning_mass)
```